# Monitor mode not working in Qualcomm QCA9377

Tags: network-monitoring

The monitor mode is not working in QCA9377 network card in any of the Debian distributions. Is there a custom fix for this anywhere? I've so far found that the kernel integration is missing. Has anyone independently tried to sort this? The kernel version is 5+ running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.